# Change Location of data in Android APK file

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I've an apk decompiled using apktool, I want to change data location of this apk file from data/data to internal `/storage/emulated/0`.

Please inform which file needs to be edited for this in my decompiled apk. In short, I'm trying to decompile and edit an apk using apktool and want to change the location from `/data/data/..` or `/data/user/0` or wherever current apk stores data to an accessible location (either internal or external) so that I can access them with tools like 'Total Commander' or 'X-plore File manager'

Change Location of data of Android app to an accessible location.

Comment: Accessing data directly in `/storage/emulated/0` requires to use a totally different API, so  this will be very very very complicated. A simpler alternative would be moving it to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/` (If I am not mistaken that would be the path you get by `getExternalFilesDirs`.

Comment: An app does not have the permission to change this location. But you can use a root file explorer to access /data/data.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now which file in decompiled apk would contain getFilesDir(), so that I can replace it with getExternalFilesDir()

Comment: @MKK - you'll have better luck building a sample application with/without Proguard and disassembling that in Apktool. You'll learn what methods become and how to do replacements.

Its not always as easy as saying replacing x with y.